# Can I hide the toolbar in Safari while in Full Screen mode?

Tags: safari, fullscreen

When in non-full-screen mode, Safari lets me use the <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>|</kbd> shortcut or **View > Hide Toolbar** to hide the URL and search bar, etc. However, when I'm in Full Screen mode, this option is greyed out. Is there any way I can hide it without exiting Full Screen?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

In Safari 10.0.1 on macOS Sierra it is quite simple - you have to uncheck **View** > **Always Show Toolbar in Full Screen** to hide the toolbar.

[image: **View** > **Always Show Toolbar in Full Screen**]

Comment: This should be the top-voted answer.

Comment: Note that you might have to go into Full Screen mode before you can uncheck it

Comment: I feel like an idiot that I had to Google this and didn't just find it in the menus.

Answer (score 10):

Enter full screen mode, right-click anywhere around the address bar then click "Hide Toolbar" in the menu that appears.

[image]

Although next time you enter full screen mode the toolbar comes back.

Comment: Be careful, because once you do this, the only way to get the bar back is to exit and then enter full screen mode again.

Comment: no, you can click view/customize toolbar... to restore it

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in Mavericks.

Comment: Checkout my solution below. It'll work with Mavericks.

Answer (score 9):

Open console (⌥⌘C or **Develop > Show Error Console**), paste this code:

```
(function() {
  var el = document.createElement('div'),
      docEl = document.documentElement;

  el.innerText = 'Go to fullscreen view';
  el.setAttribute('style', 'position: fixed; top: 10%; left: 10%; padding: 30%; background: #000; color: #fff; opacity: .7; cursor: pointer;')
  document.body.appendChild(el)

  el.onclick = function() {
    if (docEl.requestFullscreen) {
      docEl.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (docEl.mozRequestFullScreen) {
      docEl.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (docEl.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
      docEl.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    }
    document.body.removeChild(el);
  };
})();
```

and click the black box.

You need to activate Developer-Tools for this solution. To enable Developer-Tools, go to Advanced, click "Show Develop menu in menu bar" at the bottom of the window.

Comment: i wonder if this could be made into a bookmarklet

Comment: `javascript:document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen()`

Comment: @ralfix, your solution won't work since Webkit-based browser require function like this triggered by user action (via click event for example).

Comment: @rgtos: It actually works fine for me, using Safari 8.0.8.